# Exercise 4.10 in Stein's Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

I am currently working on the Exercise 4.10 in Stein's Complex Analysis:

Suppose $f(z)$ is an entire function that satisfies
$$|f(x+iy)|\leq ce^{-ax^2+by^2}$$
for some $a,b,c>0$. Let
$$\hat{f}(\zeta)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2\pi i x\zeta}dx$$
Prove that $\hat{f}$ is an entire function of $\zeta$ that satisfies
$$|\hat{f}(\xi+i\eta)| \leq c'e^{-a'\zeta^2+b'\eta^2}$$
for some $a',b',c'>0$.

I was able to prove that $|\hat{f}(\zeta)|\leq c'e^{-a'\zeta+b'\eta^2}$. However, I'm having a hard time showing that $\hat{f}$ is entire. Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Having thought about it some more, how about the following by the Liebniz integral rule:

$$\hat{f}(\zeta) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2\pi i x\zeta} dx= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{2\pi x\eta}\cos(2\pi z \xi)dx - i\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{2\pi x\eta}\sin(2\pi x\xi)dx$$
Then,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}\hat{f}(\zeta) = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{2\pi x \eta}\cdot 2\pi x\sin(2\pi x\xi)dx-i\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{2\pi x\eta}\cdot 2\pi x\cos(2\pi x \xi)dx$$
and
$$i\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}\hat{f}(\zeta) = i\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2\pi xf(x)e^{2\pi x \eta}\cdot \cos(2\pi x\xi)dx+\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2\pi xf(x)e^{2\pi x\eta}\sin(2\pi x \xi)dx$$
It follows that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}\hat{f}(\zeta) = 0$. Is this sufficient to show that $\hat{f}$ is entire?

Comment: Wouldn't that upper bound be sufficient? If the function has a pole then it will certainly violate the upper bound, so it must be entire.

Comment: That's true, but does the upper bound tell us anything about removable singularities and essential singularities? To show it is entire, could we just take $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{\zeta}}$?

Comment: I think my argument can be adapted to eliminate the possibilities of essential singularities, and I doubt whether removable singularities should be considered as they automatically get handled by power series expansion.

Answer (score 1):

The following method is similar to the proof of Theorem 3.1 in the same chapter; we are going to use some results from Chapter 2 of the same book.

Let $l>0$ and $\zeta\in S_l:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |Im(z)|<l \}$. We show that $\hat{f}$ is holomorphic in each $S_l$.

First we let $\hat{f}_n(\zeta)=\int_{-n}^{n}f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\zeta} \, dx$, each $\hat{f}_n$ is holomorphic by Theorem 5.4 of Chapter 2. In addition, one can show that (using the given condition of $f$)
\begin{align*}
|f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\zeta}|\leq ce^{\frac{\pi^2}{a}l^2}e^{-a(x-\frac{\pi}{a}Im(\zeta))^2}
\end{align*}

Then the integrability of $e^{-Ax^2}$ (where A is a constant) implies that
\begin{align*}
|\hat{f}(\zeta)-\hat{f}_n(\zeta)|\leq ce^{\frac{\pi^2}{a}l^2} \int_{|x|\geq n} e^{-a(x-\frac{\pi}{a}Im(\zeta))^2} \, dx \rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
uniformly on $S_l$ as $n$ goes to infinity. So $\hat{f}$ is entire by Theorem 5.2 of Chapter 2.